# Fluentd creates redundant directory with no placeholders replaced

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fluentd

I’m new to fluentd. I’ve set it up as a log collector for a simple docker compose setup. Fluentd is running inside the Docker container, with following config:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match *.**>
  @type copy

  <store>
    @type file
    path /fluentd/log/run.%Y-%m-%d/docker.log
    flush_at_shutdown

    <format>
      @type json
    </format>

  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```

The directory `/fluentd/log/` is mounted (via Docker volume) to some path on the host, let's say it's `/tmp/logs/`

This config works and the logs are correctly collected. However, if I check the directory `/tmp/logs` there are actually two directories present, while redundant one has another empty directory inside:

```bash
$ tree
.
├── run.2023-11-02
│   └── docker_0.log
└── run.%Y-%m-%d
    └── docker

3 directories, 1 file
```

It looks like fluentd is creating the directory structure from `path` config param, taking it as plain string - with no placeholders replaced.

The problem is definitely not mission-critical, since `docker_0.log` contains the logs I was expecting. I just wonder why `run.%Y-%m-%d` is created too. Does the problem lie in my configuration, or is it just how fluentd behaves? How would I get rid of this dummy directory?

Thanks in advance.